# In Scala how to find THE effective implicit methods, declarations and conversions during an execution

Tags: scala, akka, marshalling, implicit-conversion, implicit

Trying to understand akka marshalling/unmarshalling and found a lot of scala implicit magic that goes on in the background and under the hood.

Question:
Is there a way to find which implicit constructs are effective during an execution.
Things that would be useful to know:
- what implicit declarations and conversions are effective
- where they are declared

What I'm thinking is an IDE plugin for this may be? To be used during code debug?

I think this would help in understanding akka marshalling/unmarshalling but also it would be useful generally wherever complex implicit features are used.

Comment: Not exactly an answer but I find e.g. `reflect.runtime.universe.reify("1".toInt).tree` in a REPL to be super useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicits are selected at compile time.

With `-Xlog-implicit-conversions`:

```
scala 2.13.0-M5> "42".toInt
                 ^
                 applied implicit conversion from String("42") to ?{def toInt: ?} = implicit def augmentString(x: String): scala.collection.StringOps
res0: Int = 42

scala 2.13.0-M5> "42".toInt //print<TAB>
   scala.Predef.augmentString("42").toInt // : Int
```

`-Xlog-implicits` explains when implicits do not apply.

IntelliJ has "show implicits".